# Extension to icarus

Tags: gallio

Is it possible to make an extension to icarus that listens to the events from the test run and handles the result on to ie. growl.
I have been searching the internets and could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to extend Icarus (by providing a plugin that implements IPackage), but this is actually more of a generic Gallio question.

The easiest way to achieve your goal would be to implement a Test Runner Extension, see Gallio.Runner.Extensions.DebugExtension for an example.